# Possible to tell if a subclass overrode a method?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, objective-c-runtime

While working on a small project I found myself needing to do some custom drawing via `drawRect:` in one of my `UIView` subclasses.  I noticed when I overrode `drawRect:` that the default background color of the `UIView` subclass had changed from transparent to black (by default background color I mean the color the view draws itself when its `backgroundColor` property is nil.)  Even with an empty `drawRect:` or a `drawRect:` that simply calls `[super drawRect:]` I noticed this behavior.

This isn't really a problem, as simply setting a `backgroundColor` to a non-nil value works regardless of whether `drawRect:` is overridden.  However, it did make me start thinking about how `UIView` knows whether `drawRect:` is overridden by a subclass.  I know Objective-C offers facilities to determine if a class or even its superclass responds to a certain selector.  But how could a superclass possibly know if its subclass has overridden one of its methods?  And, if this type of introspection is indeed impossible, what could be going on in my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is pretty bizarre (but sounds like it is intended).   Simply adding:

```
- (void) drawRect:...
{
    [super drawRect:...];
}
```

Triggers the behavior?  Atypical.     In any case, it is trivial to use the Objective-C runtime API to introspect class implementation details quite thoroughly.  See the [Objective-C runtime reference.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)

[UIView's documentation for `-drawRect:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawRect%3a) goes into considerable detail about subclassing.  It quite specifically states that you don't need to call super when directly subclassing `UIView`, indicating that the class is likely optimized to doing the minimal amount of extra work (like drawing a background that is obliterated entirely in your implementation).

Comment: Yes the behavior, surprisingly, persists even with a simple call to super.  I (stupidly) ignored the possibility of the obj-c runtime because I figured any functions used to obtain methods of a class would take the superclass's methods into account as well (so there'd always be a drawRect: present.)  But the class_copyMethodList(...,...) function (and maybe others?) seems to exclude superclass methods so I suppose UIView could iterate through that list to look for drawRect: in a subclass.  I guess the question then is if that is indeed happening.  Thanks so much for your input.